# Why does my array filter return 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
var options = [{
    "n":   function(a){return a;},
    "l1":   function(a){return a.duration<1;},
    "1to3": function(a){return a.duration>=1 && a.duration<3;},
    "3to6": function(a){return a.duration>=3 && a.duration<=6;},
    "6to10": function(a){return a.duration>=6 && a.duration<=10;},
    "m10": function(a){return a.duration>10;}
}];

var e = document.getElementById('duration');
var selopt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var arr = arr.filter(options[ selopt ]); //This line returns the error
```

I get this error at the line I specified. The array `arr` is an object array with a duration value. I know that selopt returns the correct value, so I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: You haven't defined `arr` yet, so you can't call `arr.filter`

Comment: Also, options is an array with one object. I think you meant to write `var options = { ... }` instead.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes it is defined earlier. The array is an object array,

Comment: You need to show the earlier definition.

Comment: @Bart Solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that selopt returns the correct value

Yes, but `options[ selopt ]` doesn't.

Your `options` variable holds an array which contains one object, not the object itself. Either use

```
…options[0][selopt]…
```

or

```
var options = { // no [
    …
};
```